# What's the best way to extend the User model in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication, django-users

What's the best way to extend the User model (bundled with Django's authentication app) with custom fields? I would also possibly like to use the email as the username (for authentication purposes).

I've already seen a [few](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/) [ways](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/06/django-tips-extending-user-model/) to do it, but can't decide on which one is the best.

Comment: Most answer are outdated/deprecated. Please see stackoverflow.com/a/22856042/781695 & stackoverflow.com/q/14104677/781695 & stackoverflow.com/q/16880461/781695

Comment: @buffer - The first question you linked to (stackoverflow.com/a/22856042/781695) has now been deleted. The others are still valid.

Comment: https://learnbatta.com/blog/using-custom-user-model-in-django-23/

Comment: This blog post is useful: https://dontrepeatyourself.org/post/django-custom-user-model-extending-abstractuser/

Answer (score 312, accepted):

The least painful and indeed Django-recommended way of doing this is through a `OneToOneField(User)` property.

> ### [Extending the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)
>
> …
>
> If you wish to store information related to `User`, you can use a [one-to-one relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#ref-onetoone) to a model containing the fields for additional information. This one-to-one model is often called a profile model, as it might store non-auth related information about a site user.

That said, extending `django.contrib.auth.models.User` and supplanting it also works...

> ### [Substituting a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)
>
> Some kinds of projects may have authentication requirements for which Django’s built-in `User` model is not always appropriate. For instance, on some sites it makes more sense to use an email address as your identification token instead of a username.
>
> *[Ed: **Two warnings and a notification follow**, mentioning that this is **pretty drastic**.]*

I would definitely stay away from changing the actual User class in your Django source tree and/or copying and altering the auth module.

Comment: With this solution should you ForeignKey to User or Profile?

Comment: FYI the new (1.0+) recommended method is OneToOneField(User) http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

Comment: Shawn Rider of PBS gave some really good reasons why you should *not* extend django.contrib.auth.models.User. Use OneToOneField(User) instead.

Comment: `user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)` is this the same as `user = models.OneToOneField(User)` ? I would think the end effect is the same? But maybe the implementation in the backend is different.

Comment: @pydanny: actually he gave an argument for not *overriding* the user model

Comment: Can anyone link to Shawn Riders argument/reasoning for that?

Comment: @JeremyBlanchard: I did some digging and the best I could find is a single bullet point from this: http://birdhouse.org/blog/2010/09/13/djangocon-2010/ "you’ll have to patch every re-usable app you pull in"

Comment: @JeremyBlanchard: The full video is here: http://blip.tv/djangocon/teaching-an-old-pony-new-tricks-maintaining-and-updating-an-aging-django-project-4125255 The patching argument is the only one he makes; he didn't mention any other problems, and seemed to suggest it's not a deal-breaker (they still have some of that code in their system).

Comment: @DaveForgac the link seems broken, more details here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

Comment: @SamStoelinga from:(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield)
A one-to-one relationship. Conceptually, this is similar to a ForeignKey with unique=True, but the “reverse” side of the relation will directly return a single object.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) is some additional info about extending user models as of the django 1.7 docs

Comment: Can't I just created a new class inherited from `django.contrib.auth.models.User` if I only need a couple of additional fields for my User?

Comment: i don't know about you, but for me, `OneToOneField(User)` is very annoying for big projects! i prefer using O.O.P. (extending) in my projects!

Answer (score 240):

**Note: this answer is deprecated. see other answers if you are using Django 1.7 or later.**

This is how I do it.

```
#in models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)  
    #other fields here

    def __str__(self):  
          return "%s's profile" % self.user  

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):  
    if created:  
       profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)  

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User) 

#in settings.py
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'YOURAPP.UserProfile'
```

This will create a userprofile each time a user is saved if it is created. 
You can then use

```
  user.get_profile().whatever
```

Here is some more info from the docs

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

**Update:** Please note that `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` is deprecated since v1.5: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#auth-profile-module

Comment: Thanks for the clear example, note that def create_user.... is not part of the UserProfile class and should be aligned left.

Comment: With this solution should other models ForeignKey to User or UserProfile?

Comment: Other models should use `user = models.ForeignKey( User )`, and retrieve the profile object via `user.get_profile()`.  Remember to `from django.contrib.admin.models import User`.

Comment: By using this method, I need to separate when I retrieve usual information (name, password) and custom one or is there a way to do it at once ? Same for the creation a new user ?

Comment: Can someone explain the arguments taken by create_user_profile??

Comment: This answer & comments has become outdated e.g. AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE is deprecated, `User`

Comment: The `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` setting, and the `get_profile()` method on the `User` model, will be removed in Django 1.7.

Comment: You shouldn't link to /dev/ in the django docs, because the /dev/ branch of the docs is always changing.   The link posted for #storing-additional-information-about-users no longer arrives at a topic about that.

Answer (score 223):

Well, some time passed since 2008 and it's time for some fresh answer. Since Django 1.5 you will be able to create custom User class. Actually, at the time I'm writing this, it's already merged into master, so you can try it out.

There's some information about it in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) or if you want to dig deeper into it, in [this commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/70a0de37d132e5f1514fb939875f69649f103124).

All you have to do is add `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to settings with path to custom user class, which extends either `AbstractBaseUser` (more customizable version) or `AbstractUser` (more or less old User class you can extend).

For people that are lazy to click, here's code example (taken from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#a-full-example)):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)


class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, date_of_birth, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=MyUserManager.normalize_email(email),
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, date_of_birth, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        u = self.create_user(username,
                        password=password,
                        date_of_birth=date_of_birth
                    )
        u.is_admin = True
        u.save(using=self._db)
        return u


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
                        verbose_name='email address',
                        max_length=255,
                        unique=True,
                    )
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['date_of_birth']

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

Comment: The create_user function doesn't seem to store the username, how so?!

Comment: Because in this example, `email` is the username.

Comment: You need to add `unique=True` to the email field to let `USERNAME_FIELD` accept it

Comment: Hi, I was trying to create custom user as you said but couldn't able to login using email of custom user email. would you not mind to say why?

Comment: I can't really help you without specifics. It'd be better if you created new question.

Comment: get the following error when we run syncd which lead to create super user:


TypeError: create_superuser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'email'

Comment: The custom fields are normal model fields, you can access them from templates using eg. `user.custom_field`.

Comment: anyone IF I need a user profile, should I extend this custom user (MyUser) e.g. like add more fields in existing MyUser or create new model e.g. Profile and then OneToOne link with MyUser.

Answer (score 63):

Since Django 1.5 you may easily extend the user model and keep a single table on the database.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("age"))
```

You must also configure it as current user class in your settings file

```
# supposing you put it in apps/profiles/models.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "profiles.UserProfile"
```

If you want to add a lot of users' preferences the OneToOneField option may be a better choice thought.

A note for people developing third party libraries: if you need to access the user class remember that people can change it. Use the official helper to get the right class

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()
```

Comment: If you plan on using `django_social_auth`, I recommend using a OneToOne relationship. DON'T use this method or it will mess up your migrations.

Comment: @Nimo : Could you elaborate or cite a reference

Comment: @buffer, it was a long while back, but I think I tried combining the `django_social_auth` plugin and defining the AUTH_USER_MODEL to the social auth user. Then, when I ran manage.py migrate it messed up my app. When instead I used the social auth user model as a OneToOne relationship s described here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10638293/977116

Comment: Probably has to do with `Changing this setting after you have tables created is not supported by makemigrations and will result in you having to manually write a set of migrations to fix your schema` Source : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Answer (score 47):

There is an official recommendation on [storing additional information about users](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users).
The Django Book also discusses this problem in section [Profiles](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter12/#cn222).

Comment: On this page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/ got to the extending model section

Answer (score 26):

The below one is another approach to extend an User.
I feel it is more clear,easy,readable  then above two approaches.

http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/

Using above approach:

1. you don't need to use
   *user.get_profile().newattribute* to access the additional information
   related to the user
2. you can just directly access
   additional new attributes via 
   *user.newattribute*

Comment: I like Scott's approach much better, based on the inheritance of the User object rather than directly off the model.   Can anyone say if this approach is not wise?

Comment: @BozoJoe - I just ran into this issue importing dump data, which appears to be a consequence of using this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840068/duplicate-key-value-error-when-running-django-tests-on-auth

Answer (score 20):

You can Simply extend user profile by creating a new entry each time when a user is created by using Django post save signals

## models.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import *
from __future__ import unicode_literals

class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user_name = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):  # __str__
        return unicode(self.user_name)

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        userProfile.objects.create(user_name=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

This will automatically create an employee instance when a new user is created.

If you wish to extend user model and want to add further information while creating a user you can use django-betterforms (http://django-betterforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multiform.html). This will create a user add form with all fields defined in the UserProfile model.

## models.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import *
from __future__ import unicode_literals

class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user_name = models.OneToOneField(User)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):  # __str__
        return unicode(self.user_name)
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from betterforms.multiform import MultiModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import *

class ProfileForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        exclude = ('user_name',)


class addUserMultiForm(MultiModelForm):
    form_classes = {
        'user':UserCreationForm,
        'profile':ProfileForm,
    }
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .models import *
from .forms import *
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class AddUser(CreateView):
    form_class = AddUserMultiForm
    template_name = "add-user.html"
    success_url = '/your-url-after-user-created'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form['user'].save()
        profile = form['profile'].save(commit=False)
        profile.user_name = User.objects.get(username= user.username)
        profile.save()
        return redirect(self.success_url)
```

## addUser.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="." method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}     
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
     </body>
</html>
```

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from appName.views import *
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^add-user/$', AddUser.as_view(), name='add-user'),
]
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for this answer. I am still struggling to understand how to link it all together in urls.py..any hints?

Comment: @sal Added urls example you can check now

Comment: Thanks!!. It helps me a lot. Good example

Comment: @AtulYadav .. what is the version of Django that you used ?

Answer (score 16):

**Extending Django User Model (UserProfile) like a Pro**

I've found this very useful: [link](https://blog.khophi.co/extending-django-user-model-userprofile-like-a-pro/)

**An extract:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)

>>> u = User.objects.get(username='fsmith')
>>> freds_department = u.employee.department
```

Comment: Done. I don't uderstand why a -1. Better an edit than a downvote in this case.

Answer (score 13):

It's very easy in Django version 3.0+ (**If you are NOT in the middle of a project**):

In **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    extra_field=models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

In **settings.py**

First, register your new app and then below **AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS**
add

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL ='users.CustomUser'
```

Finally, register your model in the admin, run makemigrations and migrate, and it will be completed successfully.

Official doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: it could be not so simple, if you are in the middle of the project, some details can be found in relevant Django ticket https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25313#comment:2

Comment: This is only a part of the story. Once you've created a custom user model, you have to separately also create a user manager, and UserCreationForm.

Answer (score 6):

It's too late, but my answer is for those who search for a solution with a recent version of Django.

`models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    extra_Field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    extra_Field_2 = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

you can use it in templates like this:

```
<h2>{{ user.get_full_name }}</h2>
<ul>
  <li>Username: {{ user.username }}</li>
  <li>Location: {{ user.profile.extra_Field_1 }}</li>
  <li>Birth Date: {{ user.profile.extra_Field_2 }}</li>
</ul>
```

and in `views.py` like this:

```
def update_profile(request, user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    user.profile.extra_Field_1 = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...'
    user.save()
```

Comment: I become an AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'profile' error when save_user_profile signal (instance.profile.save()) is fired. How did you solve this?

Comment: @fbzyx have you imported the `profile` model?

Comment: @fbzyx make sure the relation between your `user` and `profile` model is `one to one` not `one to many`

Comment: Which is  'a recent version of Django' referred to here?

Comment: @Gathide the latest version was Django 3.1 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/

Answer (score 4):

New in Django 1.5, now you can create your own Custom User Model (which seems to be good thing to do in above case). Refer to ['Customizing authentication in Django'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Probably the coolest new feature on 1.5 release.

Comment: Yes, indeed. But beware that one should avoid this unless necessary. Implementing your own for the reason in this question is perfectly valid though in case you're comfortable with the consequences documented. For simply adding fields a relationship with the regular User model [is recommended](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model).

Answer (score 4):

Here I tried to explain how to extend Django's Default user model with extra fields
It's very simple just do it.

Django allows extending the default user model with **AbstractUser**

**Note:-** first create an extra field model which you want to add in user model then run the command **python manage.py makemigrations** and **python manage.py migrate**

first run ---> **python manage.py makemigrations** then

second run **python manage.py migrate**

Step:- create a model with extra fields which you want to add in Django default user model (in my case I created **CustomUser**

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
# Create your models here.


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    mobile_no = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
```

add in settings.py name of your model which you created in my case **CustomUser** is the user model. registred in setttings.py to make it the default user model,

```
#settings.py

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.CustomUser'
```

finally registred CustomUser model in **admin.py**
#admin.py

```
@admin.register(CustomUser)
class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("username","first_name","last_name","email","date_of_birth", "mobile_no")
```

then run command **python manage.py makemigrations**

then **python manage.py migrate**

then **python manage.py createsuperuser**

now you can see your model Default User model extended with **(mobile_no ,date_of_birth)**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is what i do and it's in my opinion simplest way to do this. define an object manager for your new customized model then define your model.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin, AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

class User_manager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, gender, nickname, password):
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email, gender=gender, nickname=nickname)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self.db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, gender, password, nickname=None):
        user = self.create_user(username=username, email=email, gender=gender, nickname=nickname, password=password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()
        return user



  class User(PermissionsMixin, AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True, )
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=32)
    gender_choices = [("M", "Male"), ("F", "Female"), ("O", "Others")]
    gender = models.CharField(choices=gender_choices, default="M", max_length=1)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["email", "gender"]
    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    objects = User_manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Dont forget to add this line of code in your `settings.py`:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'YourApp.User'
```

This is what i do and it always works.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [Substituting a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) which is more customizable than [Extending the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

### [Substituting a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model):

- can add extra fields.
- can remove default fields.
- can change default `username` and `password` authentication to `email` and `password` authentication.
- must be the 1st migration to database otherwise there is error.

*You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332190/django-login-with-email#72412808) explaining how to set up `email` and `password` authentication with [AbstractUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser) or [AbstractBaseUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser) and [PermissionsMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-permissions) and you can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514354/difference-between-abstractuser-and-abstractbaseuser-in-django/72320454#72320454) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514354/abstractuser-vs-abstractbaseuser-in-django/72320454#72413859) explaining the difference between `AbstractUser` and `AbstractBaseUser`.

### [Extending the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model):

- can add extra fields.
- cannot remove default fields.
- cannot change `username` and `password` authentication to `email` and `password` authentication.
- doesn't need to be the 1st migration to database.

*You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42478191/how-to-add-extra-fields-in-user-model-and-display-them-in-django-admin#76717242) explaining how to extend [User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model) to add extra fields with [OneToOneField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/#one-to-one-relationships).

Answer (score 2):

Simple and effective approach is
models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class CustomUser(User):
     profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='...')
     other_field = models.CharField()
```

Comment: I would never use this solution. BUT as pure and really simplest solution this is the best and most correct for pure django way.

Comment: @ilyasJumadurdyew , why will 'never use this solution'? You claim it is the best and most correct, hence expected you embrace it.

Comment: I prefer to use completely custom model, and since modern systems has back and front separetely you won't be able to login in old way, also django has uncontrolled multiple login problem (you can't prevent parallel login out of the box)

Answer (score 1):

Currently as of Django 2.2, the recommended way when starting a new project is to create a custom user model that inherits from AbstractUser, then point AUTH_USER_MODEL to the model.

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Create a model called `Profile` and reference the user with a `OneToOneField` and provide an option of `related_name`.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import *
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_profile')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    try:
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance).save()
    except Exception as err:
        print('Error creating user profile!')
```

Now to directly access the profile using a `User` object you can use the `related_name`.

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    profile = f'profile of {request.user.user_profile}'
    return HttpResponse(profile)
```