# Extending User object in Django: User model inheritance or use UserProfile?

Tags: django, django-users

To extend the User object with custom fields, the Django docs recommend using [UserProfiles](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users). However, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django/44178#44178) answer to a question about this from a year or so back:

> extending django.contrib.auth.models.User also works better now -- ever since the refactoring of Django's inheritance code in the models API.

And articles such as [this](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/) lay out how to extend the User model with custom fields, together with the advantages (retrieving properties directly from the user object, rather than through the .get_profile()).

So I was wondering whether there is any consensus on this issue, or reasons to use one or the other. Or even what the Django team currently think?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending the User model with custom fields in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django)

Comment: Note: the recommendation mentioned in the question is for an outdated version of Django. Refer to the linked question above for guide in new Django versions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I vote for using **UserProfiles**.

I use several thrid party apps. And a foreign key to a User will always Point to auth.models.User.

**Example:**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User') # instead of your CustomUser
    text = ....
```

And your custom User model:

```
class CustomUser(User):
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Europe/London')

    # Use UserManager to get the create_user method, etc.
    objects = UserManager()
```

What will be happen if you access the user field through an Article instance?
This will raise an exception:

```
u = a_article.user
u.timezone

AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'timezone'
```

Maybe this isn't a problem for you and you wan't to avoid the additional DB query.
But i would use the get_profile way.

**UPDATE May, 2013**

Since Django 1.5 you can [extend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user) the default User model, or [substitute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) with a completely customized model.

**UPDATE Nov, 2016**

The above solution is obsolete, see the comment from wim

Comment: This will create dependencies issue in django 1.7 migrations

Comment: These days, any third party apps *should* have `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` as the relation, if they have hardcoded `'auth.User'` then that's the fault of third party ..

Answer (score 2):

Here is what [James Bennett](http://www.b-list.org/) says in this [blog entry about model inheritance](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/feb/20/about-model-subclassing/):

> I’d wager that probably 90% or more of the things people say they want to do with subclasses could be better accomplished by instead defining a related model and linking it back with a unique foreign key.

So I believe the best way to go is still to use an external app, such as some components of [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/), or the [django-profiles](http://github.com/olivierverdier/django-profiles) app (originally from the same James Bennett).