# extending django usermodel

Tags: django, model, django-users

i am trying to create a signup form for my django app. for this i have extended the user model. This is my 
Forms.py

```
from contact.models import register
from django import forms
from django.contrib import auth
class registerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
    model=register
        fields = ('latitude', 'longitude', 'status')
    class Meta:
        model = auth.models.User # this gives me the User fields
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
```

and this is my model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
STATUS_CHOICES = (
('Online', 'Online.'),
('Busy', 'Busy.'),
('AppearOffline', 'AppearOffline.'),)
 class register(models.Model): 

    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', unique = True) 
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=6)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=6)
status = models.CharField(max_length=8,choices=STATUS_CHOICES, blank= True, null=True)
```

i dont know where i am making a mistake. the users passwords are not accepted at the login 
and the latitude and logitude are not saved against the created user user.
i am fiarly new to django and dont know what to do 
any body have any solution .?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To inherit from django's user model, you have to something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class MyUserClass(User):
    #your fields go here
```

But another way to extend the user model, which would be suitable for you, if you just want to store latitude/longitude is to create an user profile that is realted to the user model. See here: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/06/django-tips-extending-user-model/
You can then find a solution where you can administrate the related profile through an InlineAdmin in a UserAdmin sub class!
See this for extending the admin: http://pyxx.org/2008/08/18/how-to-extend-user-model-in-django-and-enable-new-fields-in-newforms-admin/
And this for automatically creating a user profile upon creation of a new user: [Django: UserProfile with Unique Foreign Key in Django Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813189/django-userprofile-with-unique-foreign-key-in-django-admin)

Comment: Why is using the UserProfile way the best? This is the way I do it currently, but I keep telling myself that it would be better if I did it via inheritance. The blog that James Bennett wrote on extending the user model is really old. And Django has changed significantly since then. So I guess my question is: what's wrong with doing it via inheritance? Are there any problems? (Django 1.2+)

Comment: I do not think it's wrong doing it via inheritance! It depends on what you want to achieve and adding a user profile is the offically recommended way and I guess if the thing is just adding two fields itS totally ok!

Comment: thanks for the help... i did it in this way but got another problem that only one password field is shown on the form. and a link saying "change password form" but cant even access that link it gives me a page not found error. and the password is not saved in DB when i check it from django admin any help thanks

Comment: Did you unregister the original UserAdmin and register yours that inherits from the original one? (admin.site.unregister(User);
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)

Answer (score 1):

[Inheritance of "User" model good](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#id8) when you need custom methods to manipulate with user objects. To store additional information, [best way is to use separate model class for this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users). 
If you want to inline of your new fields in admin panel, you need to re register User model like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from MyApp.models import MyUserProfile

class MyUserProfileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MyUserProfile
    fk_name = 'user'
    max_num = 1

class NewUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [MyUserProfileInline, ]

# Then reregister
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, NewUserAdmin)
```

Comment: See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django