# Django user profil auto creation does not work on Admin site

Tags: django, instance

I think it's a bug on Django administration, when you add a user on the administration site and you have a automatic creation profil on your model, the site crash, due to a problem with the instance witch create the profil :

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs) :

    if created :
        data = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user = instance)
        profile = data[0]

        # Initialisation du profil
        profile.user = instance
        profile.credits = 0
        profile.score = 0

        profile.save()

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender = User,
                  dispatch_uid='create_user_profile')
```

on the admin site, the instance is not the user, the instance is the administrator user.

the solution is to delete this code when you create a user on the admin site, what about another solution ? this is annoying...

Comment: How does the site 'crash'?  Can you post a traceback?

Answer (score 1):

Try commenting out the line `profile.user = instance`.  The profile object that was created or retrieved already has the user set by `get_or_create`.

Comment: Sorry, i have complete my code.
The problem is, get_or_create take my profil (the admin profil because i'm log in the admin site), but, it should take the user profil i have created..

Comment: (1062, "Duplicate entry '9' for key 'user_id'")

Comment: `get_or_create` shouldn't cause that- are you sure this code is causing that error?

Comment: no, i mean i'm sure this line is the problem, of course if i delete the problem, there is no problem lol :) but it doesnt resolve it. i want to keep this code for auto creating the profil of the user but, it doesnt work when i create a user in the admin site, i think the problem is the same of this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813189/django-userprofile-with-unique-foreign-key-in-django-admin
The admin site save the profil before the model does...

Comment: i have resolve my problem by override the save method of the profil. like they said in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813189/django-userprofile-with-unique-foreign-key-in-django-admin)