# built-in django.contrib.auth.models.User VS own User model?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm writing a web app using the django framework and I was just wondering what are the pros/cons of using the built-in `django.contrib.auth.models.User` model over my own user model?
Please explain in terms of performance, scalability and security.

Many thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django

Comment: thanks, but the question was about how to extend the built-in User model. What I'm asking is whether I should use the built-in User model or create my own.

Comment: Isn't that exactly the answer? Do not extend the User model ... create a Foreign Key to your own Extended User Info model instead (Profile). If you still want to extend the User model there are links on how to do it in the question linked above as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *always* use the `contrib.auth.models.User` model, as many other apps also use it. Even if you want to have differences, it usually ends up being simpler to extend using a UserProfile than to try to build your own.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need to integrate with an auth backend that doesn't reasonably fit with `contrib.auth`, there aren't really any reasons to roll your own authentication app.  `auth` provides its own access control models, but if they don't match your needs you don't need to use them.  it provides a number of auth backends but if none of them are quite an exact match, then you can write your own backend and still use the rest of `contrib.auth`