# Adding custom profile field in django-registration

Tags: django, django-registration

I have added one additional field, `network`, in django-registration.

```
# in myproject.userprofile

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from myproject.network.models import Network

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    network = models.ForeignKey(Network, unique=True)

# in settings.py

AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'userprofile.UserProfile'
```

I don't need to add anything new to forms, as the network is generated based on the user's authorized email address.

So far, I have the following -- which is working, but is obviously not the best way to do it --

```
profile_additional = UserProfile.objects.create(user=User.objects.get(username=username),network=Network.objects.get(network=EmailList.objects.get(email=email).network))
```

Could you please show me the preferred way to do this same thing? I've read a couple tutorials on adding additional fields using signals, but can't seem to get it working myself. A code demonstrating how to do this would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django/965883#965883) is an example that shows you [how to use signals to create a new profile](http://bripkens.de/blog/2011/04/adding-custom-profiles-to-the-django-user-model/) if needed.

You can easily extend the example to edit your network field when your profile ist created or to check wether the network field is set every time a user is saved.