# Changing Django prebuild form to add new user

Tags: django, admin

I was given a task to add a field "location" to the django prebuilt user module
I found the location of the module itself and added the location field as well as the admin modules

eg:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    add_form_template = 'admin/auth/user/add_form.html'
    change_user_password_template = None
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'location')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'user_permissions')}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
        (_('Groups'), {'fields': ('groups',)}),
    )
```

I rebuilt the database hoping it would show up in the adding of new user form. 
But It didn't seem to work. So I assume I forgot to change something else.
I was looking around in the html code for ages trying to find the location of where the actual "change user" form is called, but couldn't find it.

I would appreciate help from someone who dealt with the pre built django admin backend before.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to modify django's user model because it complicates things. Instead, you can add a user profile as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users).

Comment: I have a question though. If i need the admin when creating a new user to specify his location in the creating new user form. How can I ask for this field to be filled out? I found this earlier question which is exactly the same as mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django

Answer (score 1):

If you want the profile to show up in the admin side, you can attach the profile as an inline and force it by unregistering the user and then re-registering it.  Here's how I do it:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from reversion.admin import VersionAdmin
from profiles.models import Profile
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    fk_name = 'user'
    extra = 0
    max_num = 1
    fieldsets = [
        ('Company', {'fields': ['company', 'office']}),
        ('User Information', {'fields': ['role', 'gender', 'phone', 'mobile', 'fax', 'street', 'street2', 'city', 'state', 'zip']}),
        ('Site Information', {'fields': ['sites']}),
    ]

class NewUserAdmin(VersionAdmin):
    inlines = [ProfileInline, ]

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, NewUserAdmin)
```