# Django-registration combine databases

Tags: python, django

I've installed the django-registration app succesfully and it works great.

But now I want that when people are logged in, they have to fill in more data about theirself.

Do I need to create an new django-app, so with a new database, or is it possible to save the data in the djano-registration app database (the database with username, password and e-mail)?

And how should I link these two databases, so everybody have his own, unique "index"-page with correct 'place'/link in/to the database?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [User-Profiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) section of the `auth` application. It explains how to create a Profile object (basically a new table, not database), that is connected to the User object, and has whatever data you add to it. It can be retrieved with [get_profile()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_profile).

Just to highlight something in the docs - get_profile() does *not* automatically create a Profile for you, you need to manually create one each time a User is created. [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django/965883#965883) gives sample code for using Signals to create a profile - after a User is created, it sends a signal to any registered process. You would need to code, and register a profile-creation function with the signal.

Answer (score 0):

The author of django-registration has also done a nice profile app. Wrapping around the User-Profiles.

Check it out at:

https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles/