# django websites and changing currency

Tags: django, currency

I've got to the end of a project to copy a site and realised I'd missed the currency changer on the current site.

so the question is simple. has anyone come across a super simple way of allowing a user to customise their view of objects on the site, for example a currency changer.

i've got an idea around what i need. 
some flags, drop a cookie, then adjust the price in a tag at template time.

just don't want to be redesigning the wheel if its already been done...

Answer (score 4):

You can use django-currencies module for handling multiple currencies in your Django projects.  It should be sufficient for 99% of the cases.

http://packages.python.org/django-currencies/

More complex user settings can be stored in User or UserProfile models, depending on your preference where to put additional user data. Discussion is available here:

[Extending the User model with custom fields in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django)