# ForeignKey vs OneToOne field django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to extend django user  with some additional fields . I found 2 different ways there

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    #other fields
```

OR

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    #other fields
```

Aren't they same? After syncing them, i saw no difference in mysql database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, why would you think that? A ForeignKey is a one-to-many relationship - ie a user could have many profiles. A OneToOne is, as the name implies, a one-to-one relationship - a user can only have one profile, which sounds more likely.

Comment: After syncing them, i saw no difference in mysql database, i was asking how it distinguish

Comment: The only difference *in the database* is a unique constraint on the column with a one-to-one. In fact, `OneToOneField` is merely just `ForeignKey(unique=True)`.

Comment: You wouldn't see any difference in your database, as syncdb does not change tables once they are defined, you would need to drop and recreate them. However you can use `sqlall` to show the different outputs - as Chris says, a OneToOne has a unique constraint.

Answer (score 4):

As @Daniel Roseman said, these are 2 different types of rdbms relationships.

You will find that it distinguishes in the situation where you will have(by mistake probably)
more than one profiles for a given user. In that situation `myuser.get_profile()` will raise
a `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception, since essentially it is doing a [`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#get) query, under the hood.

Comment: +1 Good point. You could technically use a ForeignKey, but setting it up as a proper one-to-one protects you from yourself by raising an exception if you attempt to create more than one profile.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yes. Basically if you do it with a ForeignKey you deviate so much from the django spec(since you render get_profile useless), that you're better off by naming your extension model something other than `UserProfile`.