# Creating custom users in Django and customizing the admin

Tags: django, admin

I need to create custom users in my app.

In [the example given in the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users)

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    #custom fields
```

a user must exists before creating a CustomUser.

What I want to do is to create automatically a User when I create a CustomUser.

In the CustomUser admin (only visible by the superuser), I'd like to have only the custom fields and a few fields from the User model, as well as some form to allow the superuser to change the password for existing instance.

Anybody could help?

Comment: refer this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part of your question is easy, you can use a signal:

```
def create_custom_user(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        custom_user, created = CustomUser.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_custom_user, sender=User)
```

As for the second part, theres already a change password form in the admin. To filter out the displayed fields you can create a CustomUserAdmin and register it together with the model. It's pretty self explaining in the django docs.

[django docs: list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

Comment: But if I understand well, this creates a CustomUser when a User is created. I want it the other way round. I want to have an admin to create a CustomUser, which automatically creates a User.

Comment: Then do it visa versa and set your user field to blank=True and null=True