# User authentication in django with custom user model and table

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, python-2.7

I'm fairly new to Django and wanted to ask regarding user authentication and logging in. I read the documentation and I was unable to find proper answer/direction regarding what I am trying to accomplish. Basically, I have to integrate into a legacy system, so I cannot use the default `auth_user` tables or anything like that. I have a model defined in my app as written below:

```
class User(models.Model):
    class Meta:
    db_table = 'user'
    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    active = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField("last modified")
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField("timestamp")
```

My question is, how can I make use of the above model (or what changes should I be making to it) to work with the authentication app? Right now I have the following backend for authentication as per the docs:

```
class CustomAuth(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(**credentials):
        return super(CustomAuth, self).authenticate(**credentials)

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):    
        # Check the username/password and return a User.
        if username != None and password != None:
            # Get the user
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=username)
                if user.check_password(password):
                    logger.info('User is authenticated, logging user in')
                    return user
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
           return None
```

I tried to test as per below:

```
user = authenticate(username='test@gmail.com', password='testUser')
```

I keep getting various errors such as `'module' object is not callable`. I also included my custom authentication in the `settings.py` file. Is there an example of what I am trying to do? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT**
I changed my model to the below:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as AuthUser, UserManager

# Extend the base User model
class User(AuthUser):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'

    active = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField("last modified")

    objects = UserManager()
```

Comment: have you read [this](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/06/django-tips-extending-user-model/) and [this](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django), basically you extend/relate the 'default' user model rather then make your own.

Comment: You're talking about inheriting from `User` model built into the framework? The reason why I didn't want to do it that way, it requires me to have various columns I don't need/want since i'm integrating into a legacy data model...or is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: I found an article which works for me...not sure if this is the recommended way? http://tomforb.es/using-a-custom-sqlalchemy-users-model-with-django

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like one problem is that your custom backend has two `authenticate` methods. You probably want to remove the top one.

Here's [an example](http://www.micahcarrick.com/django-email-authentication.html) of how to write a custom backend for processing email address based logins.