# Extending user with user profile in django(1.3)

Tags: django, django-users, extending

I am following the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/965883/1657010 for extending the django user to a user profile.

```
#in models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)  
    emailId = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)  
    #other fields here

    def __str__(self):  
          return "%s's profile" % self.user  

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):  
    if created:  
       profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)  

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User) 

#in settings.py
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'myapp.UserProfile'
```

What I am not sure is how do I create a user such that the UserProfile and User are both created and the custom fields in UserProfile such as emailId, dateCreated are populated?

In views.py I have the following

```
def register_user(request):

    json_data = json.loads(request.raw_post_data)
    email=json_data['email'].lower()
    pwd = json_data['password']
#hard-coded values for testing
    UserProfile.user = User.objects.create_user('john', email, pwd)
    userProfile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(emailId=email)
    userProfile.password=pwd
```

However, I get an error AttributeError: 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'user_id'.
I think I am mixing up the concepts somewhere here. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks for the replies. The code that you provided worked! 
I was also able to do the same using the following:

```
            user = User.objects.create_user('john', email, pwd)
            userProfile = user.get_profile()
            userProfile.emailId = email
            user.save()
            userProfile.save()
```

Wondering if both are similar, or if there is any benefit of one over the other by using the get_profile()

Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Yes I did replace the AUTH_PROFILE Module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to assign directly to your UserProfile class rather than to an instance of it, here:

```
UserProfile.user = User.objects.create_user('john', email, pwd)
```

You want something like this:

```
new_user = User.objects.create_user('john', email, pwd)
userProfile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=new_user, defaults={'useremailId': email})
```

Comment: End of the day.. Same answer  :)