# Connect user login views, form with pre-exist user which is created by Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

I have install Django admin & created some active user & group by admin page.
I need to do login form & views, which will check if user is valid or not do task in the basis of permission.
I have tried following steps.(for reference)

1. Copied admin login.html for testing & paste it foo_project/templates/registration/login.html
2. Added in urls.py

   from django.contrib.auth.views import login

   url(r'^login/', login),

Now by running 127.0.0.1:8080/login
When I am entering valid user-name & password its trying to open /accounts/profile/ & it's not found in urls.py. And if I am entering invalid username or password its doing nothing.

So I simple need to link a page if login successful(user created by admin) & check which type of permission & group he is.Admin created auth_user table in my db.sqlite3

I am new to Django & using version 1.6.

I read document & tried built-in login() in views.py. Got unsuccess.
Is there any built-in for above need. Please describe in depth if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In settings.py create this entry:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "your_redirect_url"
```

The user will be redirected to this page after login. Then on the url you will create which will respond to "your_redirect_url" (and should be defined somewhere in your urls.py), you can check the permissions, or groups. For more help about checking permissions, groups, you can find it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization).

The [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) decorator can be really useful on implementing your view for your "redirect_url", because you don't want anonymous users accessing to this part of the site, right?

Comment: Thanks @avenet for reply... But it still redirect me to /acounts/profile

Comment: This is a admin login file..What to do if I create custom login file ..i.e.what objects should be same to connect with auth_user

Comment: What do you mean with login file?

Comment: yes & where acounts/profile..Am i have to install or import something

Comment: I think I'm getting your point, do you need to extend the Django User with your profile data?

Comment: yes & I followed and done Documentation till admin add user..So if i left something which is needed to do for user authentication & in urls.py..Sorry if long convertation

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django

Comment: I am asking this B'coz generaly by-default acounts/profile should exist somewhere should work.Right?  Or every non staff user should treated like this

Comment: No, in Django it works this way: Django provides the most useful fields for users, if you need more than that, there are two ways: the first is creating an extra table and the other one involves extending the User model, it depends on what you need.