# Extending User model in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to register a user in django extending the `auth` module. I read from here and there and now I am all over the place and dont know what I am doing. 
Initially what I wanted to do is register a user with information **name**, **email**, **mobile** and **password**. since **mobile** is not in the default `django auth` I tried to extend `auth`.

here is the code.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class CustomerUserProfile(models.Model):  
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):  
          return "%s's profile" % self.user  

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):  
    if created:  
       profile, created = CustomerUserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)


post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from neededform.models import CustomerUserProfile

class CustomerRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required = True)
    mobile = forms.CharField(max_length = 20)


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','mobile','password1','password2')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from neededform.forms import CustomerRegistrationForm
from neededform.models import CustomerUserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def register(request):


    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = CustomerRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            f = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/registered/')

    else:
        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args['form'] = CustomerRegistrationForm()

    return render_to_response('User_Registration.html', args ,context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

This code upon execution makes an entry in `auth_user` table and an entry in `CustomerUserProfile` but the mobile coloumn is blank always. 
what else am I suppose to add in the code ?

PS. please can some one explain me what is this code doing

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):  
        if created:  
           profile, created = CustomerUserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)


post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

as I copied it from somewhere I want to know how this works actually.

Thank you.

Comment: Django is pretty detailed on how to extend the user model, either maintaining core fields and adding some additional, or totally overriding the whole user model:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong rather than sing song in praise of Django. I am a beginner and dont have too much Idea of what I am doing actually.

Comment: in the example it shows how to fetch the data and I want to store it.

Comment: Perhaps you should look at the similar question which  can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django

Comment: Nope. I cant find anything new. I am doing something silly. since a row is being created in the custom table its all connected I just dont know how to pass value of `mobile` field.

Answer (score 0):

This is a 2-year old question but I am surprised that there was no correct answer.
The mobile field is not saved in your profile, simply because you create your `CustomerUserProfile` via the post_save signal, and the mobile field is not forwarded by the post_save signal.

I would suggest to simply update your `CustomerUserProfile` when you handle form.is_valid() in your `register` function.