# When to use "AbstractBaseUser" in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

What is the difference between these two and what is the purpose of `AbstractBaseUser` when I can give any field to `User` model? Which one is better to use with `python-social-auth`?

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
```

and

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AbstractUser` subclasses the `User` model. So that single model will have the native `User` fields, plus the fields that you define.

Where as assigning a field to equal `User` i.e. `user=models.ForeignKey(User)` is creating a join from one model to the `User` model.

You can use either one, but the recommended way for django is to create a join, so using => `user=models.ForeignKey(User)`

The correct model to sublclass is `django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser` as noted here in the docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user

Comment: I think you mean `AbstractUser` instead of `AbstractBaseUser`. But I got the point. Thank you.

Comment: @norbertpy I added an edit with the link to the docs. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Is important here to understand the difference between `AbstractUser` and `AbstractBaseUser` as its explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514354/difference-between-abstractuser-and-abstractbaseuser-in-django#21514469).