# How do I display error messages when I am not looping over form fields in Django templates?

Tags: python-3.x, django-templates

My forms are not showing the error messages when I try to submit an empty form but I can see the errors while looping over the field errors in `views.py`. How do I overcome this problem?

the `template` **(Updated)**:

```
    {% block formcontent %}
    {{form.non_field_errors}}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            {{form.username.label_tag}} {{form.username}} {{form.username.errors|striptags}}
        </div>
    </div><br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            {{form.first_name.label_tag}} {{form.first_name}} {{form.first_name.errors|striptags}}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            {{form.last_name.label_tag}} {{form.last_name}} {{form.last_name.errors|striptags}}
        </div>
    </div><br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            {{form.email.label_tag}} {{form.email}} {{form.email.errors|striptags}}
        </div>
    </div><br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            {{form.location.label_tag}} {{form.location}} {{form.location.errors|striptags}}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            {{form.designation.label_tag}} {{form.designation}} {{form.designation.errors|striptags}}
        </div>
    </div><br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            {{form.password1.label_tag}} {{form.password1}} {{form.password1.errors|striptags}}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            {{form.password2.label_tag}} {{form.password2}} {{form.password2.errors|striptags}}
        </div>
    </div><br>
{% endblock formcontent %}
```

Edit 1:
**(Updated)**

```
class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
password1=forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
password2=forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
class Meta:
    model=MyRegistration
    fields=['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'location', 'designation']
    widgets={
        'username':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'first_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'last_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'email':forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'location':forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-select'}),
        'designation':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
    }

def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    if not username:
        raise ValidationError('Username is required!')
    else:
        try:
            MyRegistration.objects.get(username=username)
            raise ValidationError('This username already exists!', code='username_exists')
        except MyRegistration.DoesNotExist:
            pass
    return username

def clean_email(self):
    email=self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    if not email:
        raise ValidationError('Email is required!')
    else:
        try:
            MyRegistration.objects.get(email=email)
            raise ValidationError('This email already exists!', code='email_exists')
        except MyRegistration.DoesNotExist:
            pass
    return email

def clean_first_name(self):
    first_name=self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
    if not first_name:
        raise ValidationError('First-name is required!')
    return first_name

def clean_last_name(self):
    last_name=self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
    if not last_name:
        raise ValidationError('Last-name is required!')
    return last_name

def clean_location(self):
    location=self.cleaned_data.get('location')
    if not location:
        raise ValidationError('Location is required!')
    return location

def clean_designation(self):
    designation=self.cleaned_data.get('designation')
    if not designation:
        raise ValidationError('Designation is required!')
    return designation
```

I really have no idea what is wrong with my codes in template. I have checked, the Django documentation suggests the same way to approach such scenarios where the forms are not looped over.

Edit 2:

models.py:

```
class MyRegistration(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    location_list=[
        ('Solapur', 'Solapur'),
        ('Dhule', 'Dhule'),
        ('Other', 'Other'),
        ]
    username=models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    email=models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    location=models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=location_list, default=None)
    designation=models.CharField(max_length=70)
    is_active=models.BooleanField()
    is_staff=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    start_date=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    last_login=models.DateTimeField(null=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD='username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'location', 'designation']
    objects=FirstManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

views.py:**(Updated)**

```
def signup(request):
print('1')
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    print('2')
    if request.method=='POST':
        print('3')
        if request.POST.get('password1')==request.POST.get('password2'):
            print('4')
            fm=MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
            for field in fm:
                print("Field Error:", field.name,  field.errors)
            if fm.is_valid():
                print('6')
                fm.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Registered successfully!!')
            fm=MyRegistrationForm()
            print('7')
            cur_user=request.user
            return render(request, 'account/signup.html', {'form':fm, 'cur_user':cur_user})
    else:
        fm=MyRegistrationForm()
        cur_user=request.user
        return render(request, 'account/signup.html', {'form':fm, 'cur_user':cur_user})
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: Can you add the code of your form, too?

Comment: @vinkomlacic I have added the code you asked for. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Can you add the code of the `MyRegistration` model, too please?

Comment: And also the code of your view, please

Comment: @vinkomlacic I have added both the modules asked by you. Please check. Also, I have replaced the template code with the updated one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you raise `ValidationError` in the `clean` method, these errors get added to the `non_field_errors` attribute on the form. This is why nothing gets rendered when using `form.email.errors` and other `errors` attributes on particular fields.

You should render the `form.non_field_errors` before you render your form, so you can see those errors, too.

However, to solve your issue, I would rather go with the option of splitting the validation of each field into particular methods `clean_<field_name>`. For example for username field:

```py
def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    if not username:
        raise ValidationError('Username is required!')
    else:
        try:
            un=MyRegistration.objects.get(username=self.instance.username)
            raise ValidationError('This username already exists!')
        except MyRegistration.DoesNotExist:
            pass

    # Make sure you return the value of the data in 
    # the clean_<field_name> methods
    return username
```

And so on for other fields, too. Doing just this should fix your code, but here are some other recommendations:

- Use codes when raising `ValidationErrors`. E.g.: `raise ValidationError('This username already exists', code='username_exists')`
- Check out the django-crispy package, it can handle the HTML rendering of forms with minimal code
- You can set constraints in the models for unique fields (e.g. username) and required fields. This further prevents users who are not adding data with your form (e.g. admin) to add duplicate usernames or null values. This would also mean that a lot of your custom validation code would be unnecessary.

**EDIT #1:**
The use of `instance` to get the values from the submitted form is wrong. Since this form is used exclusively for create purposes as registration is creation of a new user, `instance` will always be empty. `instance` is only filled with data when you're updating a model instance.

You should replace the uses of `instance` with getting the form data from `self.cleaned_data` dict.
For example:

```py
# Instead of:
username = self.instance.username
# Use:
username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
```

**EDIT #2:**
*After the author added the view code.*

The issue might be in your view code. Also, there is no need to comparing `password1` and `password2` as the `UserCreationForm` already does that for your.

The **core issue** is that if your form is invalid, you need to re-render that same form, not create another instance. I propose the following update:

```py
def signup(request):
    print('1')
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        print('2')
        if request.method=='POST':
            print('3')
            form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                print('4')
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Registered successfully!!')
            # If you do this, you always render the empty form
            # without the errors
            # fm=MyRegistrationForm()
            print('7')
            cur_user=request.user
            return render(
                request, 'account/signup.html', 
                {'form': form, 'cur_user':cur_user}
            )
        else:
            form = MyRegistrationForm()
            cur_user=request.user
            return render(
                request, 'account/signup.html', 
                {'form':form, 'cur_user':cur_user}
            )
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Some other recommendations:

- You probably don't need to check if the user is authenticated if this is registration view. How can the new users create an account? However, if this is needed probably the `@login_required` decorator works better for this.
- On success, you need to redirect to the success URL. Don't use `render` for success scenarios, only when handling the GET method or when you need to re-render the form to display validation errors.

Comment: It didn't help actually. I tried rendering the `form.non_field_errors` , didn't work. Created separate `clean` methods for each fields too, no effect!

Comment: Can you add what you see in the errors?

Comment: I tried testing this, and it works for me (`non_field_errors` get rendered). So, I suspect the errors might be in views or model code.

Comment: I also added an edit regarding the use of `self.instance`

Comment: That is the problem, there's no error showing. The form just stays intact when I'm  submitting it totally blank, no errors, nothing. So it's become impossible to track down the core issue here.

Comment: I have also updated the `MyRegistrationForm` in my post where I did use the cleaned_data approach but to no avail. Hope you find something in the model or the  view function there.

Comment: I updated the answer to add a correction for the view method

Comment: I have updated the view function in my post. Please let me know if this was what you recommended and, if yes, then sadly, that didn't work out too!
And about the authentication of the user, actually, The new users can only be created by the superuser.

Comment: Another question, will the password matching feature work automatically when I have created my user model by inheriting `AbstractBaseUser` and I'm not using the `UserCreationForm`?

Comment: I would also like to mention that none of the forms in my apps display the errors. I have posted this particular form as an example. If this gets fixed, probably others will too.

Comment: The password matching feature depends on the fact that your fields are named `password1` and `password2`. If this is true, it will work. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049916/when-to-use-abstractbaseuser-in-django)

Comment: PS, I don't see any updates in the original post. Is the current code in the post what you tried?

Comment: You still have the problematic line `fm=MyRegistrationForm()` there. Please try the code as suggested in the answer.

Comment: I really misread that line. It WORKS now!! Thanks a ton!