# Django, relate User with another table

Tags: database, django, model, relationship

So I got the tables you can see in the image below:

[image: database]
.

What I would like to do is to create a relationship so that each user (of django **auth_user**) will be enrolled(or able to enrol) to exactly one "**course**" so that he will be able to see next events for his modules.

Do I have to create another table and place 2 foreign keys or this is a way to do it in 'php' and it's more simple with Django? I was suggested to create 'student' model inheriting from 'User' with extended behavior and **one to many relationship** on auth. I tried to do that but unfortunately had not results since I'm really new to Django & Python.

Answer (score 3):

If every auth_user (or auth.User) will be or have the opportunity to be enrolled on a course I would create a 'user profile' model that has a 1-to-1 relationship with the django User model. You can store additional User data in this model, including what course they are enrolled on. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model for more details but here is an example:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User')
    course = models.ForeignKey('courseapp.Course', null=True)
```

You would probably need to create a signal that gets fired each time an auth.User object is saved, such that if it is the first time that User object has been saved, it automatically creates the UserProfile:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from yourusersapp.models import UserProfile

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # Automatically creates a UserProfile on User creation.
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

When you query a User object, you can then reference the User object's profile like:

```
user_object.userprofile
```

You could then create a Course object and link the user_object indirectly via its UserProfile to that Course:

```
course = Course.objects.create(name='course_name', next_field='whatever')
user_profile = user_object.userprofile
userprofile.course = course
userprofile.save()
```

Now you have a user object with a UserProfile that is linked to only 1 course. Many users can be on the same course, but a user can only be on 1 course. You can also reference all users on a particular course like:

```
course = Course.objects.get(name='course_name')
course_users = course.userprofile_set.all()
```

HTH

Comment: Answered my own question, it should reside in `models.py`, as noted in @Raisins's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/965883/4648080).

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can go about this one of two ways.

1. Extend the User model. 'Student' would probably be a good name for your new model. It would have a OneToOne relationship with 'User', and a ForeignKey relationship with 'Course'. It can store any other information that is applicable to students only. Documentation for how to do that can be found here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model
2. Create a custom User model that has a ForeignKey relationship with Course. This approach is a bit more complicated, but yields a slightly cleaner end result. Documentation for that is here. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Sorry if it seems like I'm just sending you to the Django docs, but both of those sections are well written and should explain things pretty clearly. If you'd like to post another question with example code we can try and see why your original attempt at extending the User model didn't work. By the way, your "Student" model shouldn't have to inherit from the User model in order to extend it.

Comment: The thing is that I won't add any extra fields to the user model so I'm not sure if it's a good idea to create a custom User model. So the 1st way is better in my case?
Also since in the future I may add "teachers" it wouldn't be better to follow the 1st way?
Sorry if i'm confusing you.

Comment: Yes. I think that the first way is a simpler (better) approach for you at this time. Especially if you are new to Django/Python.

Adding a 'Teacher' object should be simple enough once you have gotten the 'Student' one working.

Comment: Great! I'll take the first way then! Thanks a lot! I'll let you know the results!