# Django - User custom field

Tags: python, django, model

Hi I'm new to Django and I'd just like to ask what's the best way to add a custom profile field (e.g. companyid).

I'm reading this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/

Should I just create 2 new apps? Company App and then User Profile app?

I'm looking to use the CompanyID as a criteria / filter that will be used in page views.

Linked answer / solution is outdated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django provides examples of creating a OneToONeField and creating custom user model

Comment: @dm03514 do you have a sample of how to use OneToOneField(User)?