# Django customizing 'add user' request of admin app

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-authentication

I am trying to customizing django admin app to achieve following requirements.

After when user hit 'add user', I want to make entries in some more databases related new user. 
I am using multiple databases with help of routers. How to catch this add user request.

I don't want to completely replace 'adding user' functionality but want to some extra features in it.

How to achieve this?

Please let me know any idea or example.

Thank you.

Comment: plese take a look at [Extending the User model with custom fields in Django][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? If you want some code to run when a new user is created, you need to listen on the [`post_save` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/signals/); otherwise update your question with more information as to what you want to do.