# Inherit django's default user model in my model

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I have a question about django's user inheritance.

I have gone through docs of django where I have seen inheritence of User model if I want to register the user through email and password.

My questions :

What will be the difference on default User model and Custom User model that I will make ?
Can I use the permissions and add group in the Custom User model ?

And also what if I want to inherit django's default User in my model ?

```
class Person(User):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.address
```

Here the user model is django's default User model ?
Can I inherit like that ?

Comment: Similar effect with any method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django

Answer (score 3):

based on django [specifying a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model)

> The easiest way to construct a compliant custom User model is to inherit from AbstractBaseUser. AbstractBaseUser provides the core implementation of a User model, including hashed passwords and tokenized password resets.

Alse [Extending the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) can be a good option.