# Should I use my own users table or use the admin generated one with django?

Tags: python, django, admin

I created my own user table. I've been learning how to use the admin panel and I saw there's already a user table.
Should I use it or mine? (for example connection, member panel etc...)
If I should use it how to update it?
If I shouldn't what do I have to use it for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the one django provides.

If you want extra fields on your user, create an extension to the user model.

It's really easy to do, you can just create your own model and make it inherit from the django.contrib.auth.User model, or you can also look here: 
[Extending the User model with custom fields in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django)  for more awesome answers of how people are doing this exact thing

Comment: As an aside, I'd say use the built-in `django.contrib.auth.models User` model because of all the stuff it does for you - but don't feel obligated to use the built-in Django admin panel that comes preinstalled at `http://www.mydjangosite.com/admin`. I only mention this because OP specifically mentioned the admin panel in his original question. It's a great starting point, but it's a little inflexible and not really suited for use by anyone other than the root user.

Comment: @souldeux true; we build a few products using the admin. hard to do a django upgrade without breaking a lot of stuff. Since it's very not flexible enough, we had to copy templates a few times, and again, at django upgrade time we shot ourselves in the foot.