# Django User belongs to Company

Tags: django

I am really new to Django, I would like to have users, that belong to a company, so many users to a single company. Do I need to copy the existing user model and add to my project? Where would I find the User model to extend?

Sorry if this is not very descriptive it is my first project with python and django.

Comment: yes, make a custom user model with a company field https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending the User model with custom fields in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(If you need many companies to one user) you don't need to copy the user model. Just create a "Company" model and use "ForeignKey".
Example:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Opposite(If you need many users to one company):

```
#settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User'

#myapp.models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as BaseUser, UserManager
class User(BaseUser):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    # Use UserManager to get the create_user method, etc.
    objects = UserManager()
```

Comment: Does this not relate a Company to a User rather than a User to a Company?

Comment: Please read this article:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: Note that it is in general a good idea to start a Django project with a custom User model, even if you don't change anything (because changing a customer user model later is much easier than changing the default user model later). Doubly so if you have an actual reason.