# Register custom user model with admin auth

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-authentication

In a Django project, I have a custom user model that adds one extra field:

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, blank=True)
```

This model is defined in my app, say `MyApp.models`.

How can I get the new `User` model to show up under "Authentication and Authorization" as the original `django.contrib.auth` model?

[image]

Comment: Where you able to achieve this?

Comment: No unfortunately

Comment: Did you fix this yet?

Answer (score 1):

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    class Meta:
    app_label = 'auth'
```

This can solve your problem but may cause some errors when you migrate your app. The other hack is define `get_app_list` in your `AdminSite`.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is replacing the django user model. To do this, see the answer on this post: [Extending the User model with custom fields in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django). I would suggest going the extending route, but that would mean both parent and child model would have to be registered.

If you really want one single model, just set the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting to your model. This essentially replaces the default model.

In your settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "appname.UserModelName"
```

For more info on replacing the user model, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model.

Answer (score 0):

In admin.py use

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

UserAdmin.list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active', 'date_joined', 'is_staff')

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: That is what I'm doing, but a) if I use *my* `User` class, it appears in my app; b) if I use Django auth's class, it doesn't appear anywhere (not surprising since that's not the class I'm using to represent the user).

Comment: I have a superuser, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to try this:

https://libraries.io/pypi/django-modeladmin-reorder

*Custom ordering for the apps and models in the admin app. You can also rename, cross link or exclude models from the app list.*

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the new User model to show up under "Authentication and
> Authorization"

I had the same concern using Django 3.0, this is how I solved it :

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    
     class Meta:
         db_table = 'auth_user'
         app_label = 'auth'
```

In settings :

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "auth.CustomUser"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class AdminExtra(UserAdmin):
    add_form_template = "admin/auth/user/add_form.html"
    change_user_password_template = None
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {"fields": ("username", "password")}),
        (_("Personal info"), {"fields": ("first_name", "last_name", "email", "nick_name")}),
        (
            _("Permissions"),
            {
                "fields": (
                    "is_active",
                    "is_staff",
                    "is_superuser",
                    "groups",
                    "user_permissions",
                ),
            },
        ),
        (_("Important dates"), {"fields": ("last_login", "date_joined")}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (
            None,
            {
                "classes": ("wide",),
                "fields": ("username", "password1", "password2"),
            },
        ),
    )


admin.site.register(User, AdminExtra)
```

Comment: Please try to add more commentary, thanks Erfan for the answer.