# django extending user model depending on user's role

Tags: python, django

I need to have 2 user roles in my project: client and employer

**Question number one**: There is an option called 'groups' in Django admin panel.Is it the same stuff like user roles?

[image]

**Question number 2**:

Let's say that I need to add custom field like `company_name` to users with role `customer`
I have read some question like this [Extending the User model with custom fields in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django) 
And I got from that I should use a property  called `OneToOneField(User)` 
But still I still confused.
So how can I add this custon field `company_name`  in model?

Comment: `Still didn't get it right` - can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to Q1:**
Groups are are for controlling the Admin interface access, with different permissions. If you try creating a group you will see that you can select permissions as well for that particular group. So I would say it is not what you want. But if you create groups without permissions you can use for your purpose as well.

**Answer to Q2:**
Please refer to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) for more details and examples.
Here is just a basic example. For your case you need to create new model which has one to one relation to you auth user model and extends more fields as you want, for example:

```
USER_TYPE = {0: 'Client', 1: 'Employer'}

class MySpecialUser(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
  )
  type = models.IntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE.items())
  # used only for Client type
  customer_name - models.CharField(..., null=True)
```

Comment: can you tell me line by line how your example works?

Comment: I didn't gave you full working example, and its better you ask which part is not clear, i will try to improve the answer. For more exhaustive examples please refer to tutorials.

Comment: I don't really get this lines:   # used only for Client type
  customer_name - models.CharField(..., null=True)

Comment: how it will be used only for Client type? which line does that?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I mean in you case you set value for customer_name only for Client type users for employees you can leave that field to be Null.