# User Model fields not showing in Django Admin Panel

Tags: python, django

I have a basic model that extends the User model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Promotion (models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(User)
    Rating = models.ForeignKey(Rating)
    Date_Effective = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Rating.Rank.Short_Rank + ' ' + self.User.last_name + ' (' + str(self.Date_Effective) + ')'
```

in my Admin.py, i have the models showing:

```
admin.site.register(models.Promotion)
```

when loading a promotion, the `Short_Rank` field and the `Date_Effective` fields show perfectly, but the `User.last_name` does not.

```
ADM (2017-03-18)
```

[image]

This is consistent with the rest of the models, and I am believing that the User model itself is not being attacked by the query in the admin panel.  How do I get the name fields in the User model showing in the model page of the Admin panel?  Thanks.

Comment: Does the related `User` have a `last_name`? Btw, your model is by no means "extending" the `User` model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have one to one relation when you want to extend the auth user. Please refer to this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django?rq=1) .

Here is how you can change it and I expect it should work for you:

```
class Promotion (models.Model):
   User = models.OneToOneField(User)
   Rating = models.ForeignKey(Rating)
   Date_Effective = models.DateField()
```