# Django - how to query user profile based on User model having OneToOneField

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django and new to programming. I want to know how can I query the profiles of the user which has OneToOne relation with User model. Here is my code:

models.py:

```
class User(models.Model):

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=22)

class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    contact_person = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

If a user signup and after verification fills in his profile. How can I query the database through views.py that for any particular User what is his UserProfile information. For example what is the company_name or country for a user with email example@examplemail.com

Just on the side note also is this the best practice I'm doing to capture additional information about user in Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the User and use its UserProfile like so:

```
# Make sure you create a UserProfile when you create a new User
user = User.objects.get(email='example@examplemail.com')
user.userprofile.company_name
user.userprofile.country
```

Yes, this is a recommended way to add extra fields to the default django User model. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django) question. If you are using your own User model you could just add the UserProfile fields to the User model.