# How can I add an option to add more fields while creating a new user in django

Tags: python, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkCyf.png)I was following the official documentation of django and I need help with being able to add a option to the admin site where I can add a option to add a new field like along with customer name and password also an ID so how can i add the ID option on the page itself ?

Comment: In which model do you want the `ID` field

Comment: I want to add a option on the web page itself to add a new field whenever i am creating a new user

Comment: If you want to add new field to default `User` model, then you can use `AbstractBaseUser` to extend the `User` model, or you can extend it with new model and using `OnetoOne` relation between them

Comment: this may be helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django

Comment: What page is 'the page'? The admin page? Your custom view page? Anything you did so far? @Bijoy is right, first add the field to your User model. Extend with a OneToOne field https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user OR substitute the existing User model https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user

Comment: see the picture attached suppose I want to add a new field while creating a new customer how can it be done ?

Comment: Add the field to the model (like pointed out in the docs). After that unregister the existing User ModelAdmin and register a custom ModelAdmin containing your field. See the admin.py code here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: i want a way to add the field to the model through the web page itself not using the models.py file

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is create other class like CustomAdmin and use OnetoOne realation.

For example:

```
class CustomAdmin(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  blank=True, null=True, related_name='user_customUser')
username = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Username')
web_custom = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Web')
phone_custom = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Phone')
```

Comment: i think I wasnt able to explain my question properly you see the picture there when i am adding a customer there are 5 fields user,name ,server n ol what if I want to add a new field like apple_id there itself while creating a new user will this help?