# how to extend custum user Model?

Tags: python, django

I want to create the new `UserModel` that is a Custom from User Model django, then add extended attribute and methods like Proxy model and One-To-One Link Model together. 
I want to use Authentication and permission UserModel django to my defined `UserModel` for my two type Users that are my defined `Admin` and staff `User`.
How to use just `username` and `password` for Authentication for My UserModels and other custom fields.

**How to create it and fill with the `ModelForm`?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending the User model with custom fields in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to extend AbstractUser like this :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class MyUser(AbstractUser):

    slug = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, blank=True, editable=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    picture = models.ImageField('Profile picture',
                                upload_to='profile_pics/%Y-%m-%d/',
                                null=True,
                                blank=True)
```

And so on