# How to add 'mobile' field to default auth_user table in User model in django?

Tags: python, django

I want to add Mobile filed to be saved to auth_user table when i register.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserRegModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    mobile = forms.CharField(max_length=15)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','mobile','password1','password2']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store all user data together, you should substitute a user model instead of creating a OneToOne relationship. Judging by the current code you will get 2 tables - one for standard Django user and one connected to it with mobile data.

Here you can read more about substituting a user and the difference between these 2 approaches:

[Extending the User model with custom fields in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django)

Or directly in the documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: I dont want to add extra details [mobile] in profiles. I want to store in same table auth_user.

Comment: @SumitNayak and so it will be - if you will add AUTH_USER_MODEL to settings with the path to custom user class, which extends either AbstractBaseUser (more customizable version) or AbstractUser (more or less old User class you can extend) it will add your additional fields from custom class to the standard user class and store it in one auth_user table. 
Tho, I strongly recommend to check out the first link, because this approach has its  own nuances.

Comment: Sure, Let me check

Comment: i was successful doing so, but now when im creating Registration form im not able to do so,   

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

Comment: Hey @IgorBelkov Thanks for the help, I was able to do the task.

Comment: @Sumit Nayak I glad, that it helped! Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

[Click here for the first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM5i0.png)
[Click here for the second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFjHG.png)

Do this and type these codes in terminal

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Please post a description of the solution rather than a picture of it.