# How to add new fields to users according to its group (role) in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-authentication

I'm trying to do a logistics web application in Django and I need to assign different roles to the users.

I have normal users (clients), employees (office employees, delivery man, truck drivers...) and supervisors.

I need to do the following:

- Office employees and delivery man users: need to have an office assigned
- Truck drivers users: need to have an assigned route

I've made 2 models (Offices and Routes) but I don't know how to relate the users with these models.

I've read websites that create custom classes inherited from AbstractBaseUser or AbstractUser, but I don't know how to do it with this special case.

I hope to hear the right answer here.
Thanks in advance!

Edit: my question is different as [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django), as I need to handle with different types of User, not just one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending the User model with custom fields in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django)

Answer (score 1):

You can get help from https://realpython.com/modeling-polymorphism-django-python/ and maybe the best one is Sparse Model for you

Comment: Thanks! I've seen that link and [this other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

According to these links, I understand that I have to extend User Model and add all the model fields of both types of users, and raise exceptions to overcome with integrity problems. Is it correct?

Comment: Also, how could I associate the choice list with a group? For example, if user_type = A, associate with group A

Comment: @Luis You can create a manager for each of them to filter base on the type