# How to Modify the default Django user table

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

How to Modify the default Django user table and the custom user table should consist of the 'first name','last name', 'gender', 'Email(Primary Key)', 'phone number' fields. How to do this?
forms.py

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model= User
        fields = 'First_name','Last_name','Gender', 'email','Phone_number'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extending the User model with custom fields in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create custom model to extend Django user model.
look in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

**Example with your fields**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ExtendedUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    First_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Last_name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Gender = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and then use it in your form

Comment: Although it would be much better coding style to name the fields `first_name`, `last_name`, `gender` and `phone_number` to follow PEP8.

Comment: how to do email as primary key here?

Comment: @kumar, try `email = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)`

Comment: @weAreStarDust i tried this but it showing error "user_id can not be null"