# How to add additional field in the default admin_User table in Django 3.0.3

Tags: python, django

I don't have idea to put extra field in default admin user table/ model in django 3.0.3 version . Please give some idea to make extra field like user_roll, user_id, designation etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44178/12261752

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extending the User model with custom fields in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django)

Comment: Browsing the doc before and / or doing a search before asking questions is most often a good idea...

Answer (score 1):

For that you have to extend `AbstractUser` as below and add extra field as per your requirements...

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    # Add your extra field here
    my_custom_field = models.CharField(max_length=2)
```

In this example my_custom_field would be your custom field . You have a number of options, BooleanField (true/fales), IntField ... etc) and you can add as many (within reason, as you like).

And suppose this `User` model is in app named `app_1` then you have to set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in `settings.py` as below...

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "app_1.User"
```

Run `makemigrations` and `migrate` commmand because we changed in model.

Comment: Technically, while I get what you're saying here you haven't actually shown him how to add a Field probably want give him an example