# How to add field to django.contrib.auth forms

Tags: python, django

I want to add fields to django.contrib.auth forms. Is there anyway to do that?

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model, forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
 
User = get_user_model()
 
client = Client(URL, API_KEY)
 
class UserChangeForm(forms.UserChangeForm):
 
    class Meta(forms.UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = User
       
 
 
class UserCreationForm(forms.UserCreationForm):
   
    error_message = forms.UserCreationForm.error_messages.update(
        {
            "duplicate_username": _(
                "This username has already been taken."
            )
        }
    )
   
    class Meta(forms.UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
 
    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
       
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
         
           
            return username
 
        raise ValidationError(
            self.error_messages["duplicate_username"]
        )
```

Models.py [This is my models.py file]

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class User(AbstractUser):

    # First Name and Last Name Do Not Cover Name Patterns
    # Around the Globe.
    name = models.CharField(
        _("Name of User"), blank=True, max_length=255
    )
    phone= models.CharField(
        _("Phone"), blank=True, max_length=20
    )

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            "users:detail", kwargs={"username": self.username}
        )
```

Usercreationform is basically the ACCOUNT_FORMS signup and I am using django allauth forms but I cant figure out how to add a field to it e.g phone number.

Comment: Did you make a custom user model? Does that model have phone number?

Comment: @dfundako I've added my models.py to the question. Please check

Answer (score 0):

To add a field into your form, you'd have to add the same field in the model, because that form is creating a new object from the `django.contrib.auth` User model. You can achieve this in many ways, the easiest being creating a new User model that has a ForeignKey pointing to the Django one. I'd recommend you to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44109/11556154) question or the [official Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/) regarding this topic.