# Django Scopes - How to get current tenant?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm fairly new to Django and I'm building a multi tenant app. I'm not really sure how to get the logged in user's current tenant in order to use it as a filter in views. Example: `Post.objects.filter(tenant=current_tenant)`

Example Models:

```
from django.db import models

class Tenant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(…)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    tenant = models.ForeignKey(Tenant, …)

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, …)
    title = models.CharField(…)

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, …)
    text = models.CharField(…)
```

Where should I write the `get_current_tenant` function and how should I write it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will have to [extend the user model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44109/3929826) in some way. Could be a one to one relation to or from the `Tenant`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've updated the question with the user model. Do you have any suggestions on how to write the `get_current_tenant` function and where to place it?

Comment: With that model the user is going to have an attribute `tenant`. No function needed.

Comment: I understand that I can now access the `tenant` attribute. I would appreciate it if you can explain to me how I can use it in order to make sure that `Class-based views` queries will only return the currently logged in user tenant's related instances.

Comment: Read the link I gave and the links in it!