# django custom abstractuser model authorization

Tags: django, django-models

I've user custom model and subModel Teacher and Student I want them to login in the same form:

models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    course = models.ManyToManyField(Course, related_name='student_course')
    is_student = models.BooleanField('Студент',default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField('Учитель',default=False)
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Фото',upload_to='uploads/accounts/',blank=True)

class Student(User):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Студент'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Студенты'

    def __str__(self):
        return super(Student, self).__str__()

class Teacher(User):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Учитель'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Учителя'
```

views.py:

```
def user_login(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect(home)
            else:
                return render(request,'login.html')
        else:
            return render(request,'login.html')
```

but not authorization

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extending the User model with custom fields in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django)

Comment: Have a look at (How to Implement Multiple User Types with Django)[https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html]